# External HDD Cannot Be Read

Tags: macos, mbr, gpt

I have an interesting situation.

A User brought in her external HDD which she was using to backup data on her MacBook Pro (OSX 10.12.xx), it is a WD EasyStore 1TB HDD. The User recently upgraded her OSX to High Sierra (10.13.xx).

Unbeknownst to the User Apple changed file formats to APFS. Now the hard drive shows up, but cannot be mounted. I have tried on both OSX 10.12.xx and OSX 10.13.xx. I don't know if it's native to Apple, but her HDD now appears to use GPT and not MBR (or it could have the whole time, I am not sure) so I was working with our Client SysAdmin to try to make a solution.

We created a Win10x64 environment using EUFI and formatted the hard drive of the computer as GPT.

Everything installed fine, but I am still at the same wall with being able to see the HDD in Disk Management, but not in My Computer. I am also not able to assign it a drive letter.

I am thinking the user left the HDD plugged in while doing the High Sierra upgrade which may have done something odd with the HDD. Any help would be appreciated. The User said that if she lost all her data it's okay, but I am trying to avoid that if possible.

Comment: "EUFI " - Whats that?  Windows can't mount any volume, that uses one of Apple's file systems, without third-party drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound - In order for this to work I needed to change the computer and Windows USB tool to boot in EUFI and not legacy. Most systems run EUFI firmware now I believe, but our site still uses legacy boot. I will try using some third party drivers, if you know of any in particular that work, I could definitely use the help. I appreciate your response. Sorry if my some of jargon is off, I am only a level 1 Tech for now.

Comment: You keep using the term "EFUI" I think you mean "UEFI".  EFUI isn't anything I am familiar with.  There is a reason I ask for clarification.  *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.*